# Play framework 2.2.1 Can not run application - "PAGE DOES NOT EXISTS"

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have tried to run existing play application, it compiles and runs correctly (without errors in the console).

But when I opened home page (`http://localhost:9000/`):

`PAGE DOES NOT EXISTS` message is displayed.

Also I found in the debug logs messsage:

`[application]-[ERROR] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] - SessionElements: Brand Exception Unique expecting 0 or 1 rows but got [18]`.

Could someone explain what does this message mean?

Also good to know, should be used only `play run` for project start or something else?

Console output:

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/MyProject/lib/logback_classic.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/play-2.2.1/repository/local/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0
.13/jars/logback-classic.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] application - Cobrand details added into UserSession from ConfigurationFile
[info] application - Config loaded.
09:25:34,485 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:25:34,485 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:25:34,485 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml]
at [jar:file:/C:/play-2.2.1/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.1/jars/play_2.10.jar!/logback.xml]
09:25:34,485 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@1383357 - URL [jar:file:
/C:/play-2.2.1/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.1/jars/play_2.10.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
09:25:34,563 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
09:25:34,610 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:25:34,610 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]

09:25:34,626 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default t
ype [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:25:34,641 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT
logger to ERROR
09:25:34,641 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named
 [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
09:25:34,641 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
09:25:34,641 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@b29b88 - Registering current c
onfiguration as safe fallback point
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@1315e - URL [jar:file:/C
:/play-2.2.1/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.1/jars/play_2.10.jar!/logger.xml] is n
ot of type file
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ConversionRuleAction - registering conversio
n word coloredLevel with class [play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel]
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default t
ype [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [C:\MyProject/l
ogs/application.log]
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]

09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default t
ype [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [play] to INFO
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [application] to DEBUG
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader] to OFF
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader] to OFF
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread] to OFF
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript] to OFF
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOTlogger to ERROR
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
09:25:34,657 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@501773 - Registering current c
onfiguration as safe fallback point
09:28:48,426 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
09:28:48,481 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ConversionRuleAction - registering conversio
n word coloredLevel with class [play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel]
09:28:48,481 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
09:28:48,481 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE_PLAY]
09:28:48,481 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default t
ype [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:28:48,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE_PLAY] - File property is set to [C:\MyProject/logs/application.log]
09:28:48,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:28:48,482 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]

09:28:48,483 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:16 - no applicable action for [
pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][pattern]]
09:28:48,483 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
09:28:48,484 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE_DEBUG]
09:28:48,486 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default t
ype [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:28:48,495 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
09:28:48,496 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern C:/MyProject/lo
gs/debug_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log for the active file
09:28:48,499 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date p
attern is 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH' from file name pattern 'C:/MyProject/logs/debug_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
09:28:48,499 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-overat the top of every hour.
09:28:48,501 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting in
itial period to Sat May 19 09:28:48 EEST 2018
09:28:48,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE_DEBUG] - Active log file
 name: C:/MyProject/logs/debug_log.2018-05-19_09.log
09:28:48,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE_DEBUG] - File property is set to [null]
09:28:48,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
09:28:48,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE_WARN]
09:28:48,503 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default t
ype [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern C:/MyProject/lo
gs/warn_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date p
attern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'C:/MyProject/logs/warn_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-overat midnight.
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting in
itial period to Sat May 19 09:28:48 EEST 2018
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE_WARN] - Active log file
name: C:/MyProject/logs/warn_log.2018-05-19.log
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE_WARN] - File property is set to [null]
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE_ERROR]
09:28:48,504 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default t
ype [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:28:48,505 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
09:28:48,505 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern C:/MyProject/lo
gs/ERROR/error_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log for the active file
09:28:48,506 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date p
attern is 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH' from file name pattern 'C:/MyProject/logs/ERROR/error_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
09:28:48,506 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over
at the top of every hour.
09:28:48,506 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting in
itial period to Sat May 19 09:28:48 EEST 2018
09:28:48,506 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE_ERROR] - Active log file
 name: C:/MyProject/logs/ERROR/error_log.2018-05-19_09.log
09:28:48,506 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE_ERROR] - File property i
s set to [null]
09:28:48,506 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate append
er of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]
09:28:48,509 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DB]
09:28:48,856 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@33aa43 - Driver name=MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
09:28:48,856 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@33aa43 - Driver version=
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 ( Revision: tonci.grgin@oracle.com-20110930151701-jfj14ddfq48ifkfq )
09:28:48,856 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@33aa43 - supportsGetGeneratedKeys=true
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [application] to DEBUG
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DB] to Logger[application]
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [application] to DEBUG
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE_DEBUG] to Logger[application]
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE_WARN] to Logger[application]
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE_ERROR] to Logger[application]
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [play] to INFO
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE_PLAY] to Logger[play]
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOTlogger to INFO
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
09:28:48,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1ef40eb - Registering currentconfiguration as safe fallback point
```

warning log file output:

```
2018-05-19 09:23:59,382 [application]-[ERROR] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] - SessionElements: Brand Exception Unique expecting 0 or 1 rows but got [18] 
2018-05-19 09:23:59,463 [application]-[ERROR] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] - SessionElements: Brand Exception Unique expecting 0 or 1 rows but got [18] 
2018-05-19 09:23:59,501 [application]-[WARN] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] - SessionElements:  Provider Exception null 
2018-05-19 09:23:59,555 [application]-[ERROR] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] - SessionElements: Brand Exception Unique expecting 0 or 1 rows but got [18] 
2018-05-19 09:23:59,596 [application]-[ERROR] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] - SessionElements: Brand Exception Unique expecting 0 or 1 rows but got [18] 
2018-05-19 09:25:01,634 [application]-[ERROR] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] - SessionElements: Brand Exception Unique expecting 0 or 1 rows but got [18] 
2018-05-19 09:25:01,755 [application]-[ERROR] - [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] - SessionElements: Brand Exception Unique expecting 0 or 1 rows but got [18]
```

> The issue was with application configuration, so I just added 127.0.0.1:9000 to database and all works correct. It was strange for me, that if localhost is not associated with user in the datapase then displays error page. But someone wrote it.
>   Thanks for responses!

Comment: Please provide some more details.  Is the the default play or did you wrote code / change routes / etc?
`play run` compile the code lazily so you will see errors only when trying access.  use `play start` for production.

Comment: I am using play 2.2.1. Also I did not change anything. I just picked up the project from svn and try to run it. The project works correct on linux server, but I could run it on my local pc (Windows 8.1).

Comment: by pulling from pickup and try it, I guess you mean checked out existing project, and not a default one. From what I see in the logs there is usage of DB, so maybe there is something with that.  (access to the db or expected tables/values that are missing).. Also there are other log files - checkout if they contain logs you dont see in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may also be related to cookies session of your project, look at application.conf and check out the cookies session/flash config, database config and such.

Answering your other question, sometimes you need to pass other specific configuration file like

`run -Dconfig.resources = otherconfigfilename.conf`, or application secret key like

`run -Dplay.http.secret.key="fnglksjgajadljglaj"`,

but for simpler projects sbt run does the trick